# Determining a mean camber line

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Fellow programmers,

I know this is a little outside your juridistiction, but I was wondering perhaps if you have time, if you could help me with one "procedure". Not in view of math but what would be the best way to take.

[image]
[image]

This is an airfoil / profile. Usually, profiles are defined with two sets of data. One is the position of mean camber line, given in the form of x,y where x is usually given in percentages of chord length. Second set of data is thickness at percentages of chord length. Thickness is always drawn perpendicular to the camber line(!), and that gives the profile points.

Now, I have a reverse problem - I have points of a profile, and I need to determine the position of the camber line. Method of interpolation through points can vary, but it doesn't matter, since I can always interpolate as many points as I need, so it comes to linear in the end.

Remember, since the thinkness is drawn perpendicular to the camber line, the position of camber line is not mean between the points of upper and lower  line of profile (called the back and face of profile).

---

*Edit (how this is done on paper):* Uhh, painfully and in large scale (I'm talking long A0 paper here, that is 1189x5945mm on a large drawing desk. You start by drawing a first camber line (CL) iteration through the midpoints (mean points) between the points of face and back at same x ordinates. After that you draw a lot of perpendicular lines, perpendicular to that CL, and find their midpoints between face and back (those points on face and back will no longer have same x values). Connect those, and that is your second iteration CL. After that you just repeat the second step of the procedure by drawing perpendicular lines onto that 2nd CL ... (it usually converges after 3 or 4 iterations).

---

*2nd Edit:* Replaced the picture with one which better shows how the thinkness is "drawn" onto the camber line (CL). Another way of presenting it, would be like picture no.2. If you drew a lot of circles, whoce center points are at the camber line, and whose radiuses were the amounts of thickness, then tangents to those circles would be the lines (would make up the curve) of the profile.

The camber line is not the mean line (mean between the points of face and back); it can coincide with it (therefore usually the confusion). That difference is easily seen in more cambered profiles (more bent ones).

---

3rd edit - to illustrate the difference dramatically (sorry it took me this long to draw it) between the mean line and camber line, here is the process of how it is usually done "on paper". This is a rather deformed profile, for the reason, that the difference between the two can be more easily shown (although profiles like this exist also).

In this picture the mean line is shown - it is a line formed by the mean values of face and back on the same x coordinates.

[image]

In this picture onto the mean line, perpendicular lines were drawn (green ones). Midpoints of those perpendicular lines make up for the 1st iteration of the camber line (red intermittent line). See how those circles fit better inside the airfoil compared to the first picture.

[image]

In the picture below the 2nd iteration of the camber line is shown, along with the mean line from the first picture as to illustrate the difference between the two. Those circles are fitting even better now inside (except that first one which flew out, but don't mind him).

[image]

Comment: What a rad problem.  You might have some luck at http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: How do you do it on paper right now?

Comment: @Rook: I suspect the only way to do it is basically an imitation of the method you'd use by hand. The good point is that most of the steps are pretty simple. The iteration that gets tedious, but that doesn't affect the computer...

Comment: You should add your description of the paper method to the main question.  That's definitely something that can be turned into a program!

Comment: @Rook: Then do the same in code. Believe it or not, computers are much faster in geometry calculations than humans. The algorithm you described sounds very efficient and not complicated.

Comment: @mtrw - In that case (I know I told I would handle this myself, but imitation of this process is exactly what I'm having a problem with) would you mind suggesting a general algorithm, or some kind of pseudo code how could I do it?

Comment: @slacker, @Jerry Coffin - In that case (I know I told I would handle this myself, but imitation of this process is exactly what I'm having a problem with) would you mind suggesting a general algorithm, or some kind of pseudo code how could I do it?

Comment: Looks like some kind of spline algorithm to me.

Comment: @Richard Cook - yes, the interpolation is often a spline, but all other kinds are used as well. I'm not sure if that is what you ment by "spline algorithm".

Comment: I'm not totally certain what I mean either ;-), but it sounds like a natural cubic spline would do the trick. You have three fixed points (the start of the camber, the end of the camber and the mean point) and the natural cubic spline is the smoothest curve that will go through this fixed set of three points. As for computing it, I'd have to think about that for a while.

Comment: @Richard Cook - Uhmm, I think you've misunderstood my problem. I'm not sure but your last comment leaves me with that impression. I don't have the camber line. All I have is a set of points that form the face and back lines of a profile (they're not equidistant nor anything). After that I interpolate through them (several methods), and get a set of (appropriate) number of points (of face and back). And then I need to determine! the position of the camber line. (Also, please, read the part about thickness being perpendicular to the CL)

Answer (score 4):

From what I can gather from your diagram, the camber line is defined by it being the line whose tangent bisects the angle between the two tangents of the upper and lower edges.

In other words, your camber line is always the mean point between the two edges, but along a line of shortest distance between the top and bottom edges.

So, given the y-coordinates `y=top(x)` and `y=bot(x)`, why don't you:

```
<pseudocode>
for each x:
  find x2 where top(x)-bot(x2) is minimized
  camber( mean(x,x2) ) = mean( top(x),bot(x2) )
</pseudocode>
```

and then interpolate etc.?

[image]

### edit

Sorry! On second thought I think that should be

```
  find x2 where ( (top(x)-bot(x2))^2 + (x-x2)^2 ) is minimised
```

obviously you should be minimising the length of that perpendicular line.

Is that right?

Comment: The 90 deg is between the bisect line and the red line, right?

Comment: the red line bisects the angle between the tangents. the red line is the tangent to the camber, and is determined by the fact it is the same angle from the upper tangent and the lower tangent, along a line where the distance above and below is minimised. The point is that, the two angles marked in red are the same.

Comment: How can it be between the red line, and the tangent to the camber? Isn't the red line the tangent line?

Comment: .. but, yes, I think you have something here ... +1 for the effort until I verify that this works ;-) (btw, what did you draw that in?)

Comment: yes sorry you are right, the red line is tangent to the camber.

Comment: Hahahahaha :))) - Oh, I don't think I'll have a funnier minute than the one I just had upon reading this, for the rest of the week :)))

Comment: @Sanjay - I've tried your first approach yesterday, but it didn't quite work. Will try your second one today. However, to clear up the confusion I've illustrated the difference between the mean and the camber line on an example. Hope it is a little clearer now (my first explanation was totally confusing, I see that now).

Comment: I wanted to draw the same picture. You can choose a point on the lower surface and then move along the upper surface until you find a segment whose perpendicular bisector also bisects the angle of the top and bottom tangent lines (as drawn here). This segment will then have a midpoint on the camber line.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to stack overflow but this is a problem I have worked on quite a bit and thought I would post an alternate approach to the problem. 
This approach uses the concept of a Voronoi diagram:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram
Essentially, a map is created which divides the space into regions containing one of the input points (x,y of your airfoil). The important part here is that any point within the region is closest to the input point in that region. The nodes created by this space division are equidistant to at least three of the input points.

Here is the interesting part: three equidistant points from a center point can be used to create a circle. As you mentioned, inscribed circle center points are used to draw the mean camber line because the inscribed circle measures the thickness.

We are close now. The nature of the voronoi diagram in this application means that any voronoi node inside of our airfoil region is the center point of one of these "thickness circles." (This runs into some issue very close to the LE and TE depending on your data. I usually apply some filtering here).

Basic Structure:

```
Create Voronoi Diagram
Extract Voronoi Nodes
Determine Nodes Which Lie Within Airfoil
Construct Mean Camber Line From Interior Nodes
```

Most of my work is in Matlab which has built in voronoi and inpolygon functions. As such, I'm not a huge help in developing those functions but they should be well documented elsewhere.

Trailing Edge/Leading Edge Issues

As I am sure you have experienced or know, it is difficult to measure thickness well when close to the LE/TE. This approach will contruct a fork in the nodes when the thickness circle is less than the edge radius. A check of the data for this fork will find the points which are false for the camber line. To construct the camber line all the way to the edge of the foil you could extrapolate your camber line (2nd or 3rd order should be fine) and find the intersection.

Comment: I was excited to see this new method, but a little disappointed when I applied the calculations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065064) and was left looking at a very zig-zaggy MCL. Results were considerably better though when I increased the point density on my section. Just wanted to pass that along. BTW, I work with compressor blade and vane airfoils, trying to put on LE profiles after forging/trimming, and those 'edge issues' you mentioned were about to drive me crazy. Thanks for restoring my sanity!

Comment: Glad you tried it out and that it worked reasonably well. Point density is a big constraint of this problem. If you imagine a circle being fit to the points along top or bottom, the distance between the points will create an arc of that circle outside of the profile. You can calulcate the approximate error in this as: (thickness)/2*(1-sqrt(1-(pointSpaceing/thickness)^2))). My main application for this is with parameter extraction of CMM data for turbine airfoil section inspection. Luckily we work with equipment that allows for very high point density and this approach has worked well for us.

Comment: Also, if you spend a lot of time working with blades and vanes (I sure do). You may find these papers of interest: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00170-005-0046-5?LI=true#page-1. This one is paid and ultimately did not work for my application but a good read none-the-less: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5585336&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D5585336 Happy turbining!

Comment: I am using it for exactly the same purpose, also (occasionally) for low-pressure turbine section parts. My point density can also be very high - I typically create splines thru the CMM points and then I can resample them as tightly as I want. Speaking of splines, I thought that as a final 'finishing' pass I would 'walk' the MCL spline: take a normal, find the (2) intersections of that with the AF spline (ccv and cvx), and tweak the MCL point along the normal to equalize the distances. One pass should do it I would think. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Interesting, I'll be interested to hear how that works for you and give it a try myself. I'm still in the development phase of things on my end but am really excited about the potential for the Voronoi method. It may not be the end-all or the proper solution but it seems novel in this realm. Cool to find a fellow ME here doing the same stuff! I'd love to bounce ideas that may not be super pertient to this thread. If you're interested, I believe my email is available in my profile.

Comment: Nope, not visible to me. I'm wondering if you're in my corporate phonebook, but nothing yet. I'll bet that if you don't work at a large aerospace manufacturer in Hooksett that you certainly know about them!

Comment: For the benefit of other readers, here is an example of the point density issues we are talking about: http://i45.tinypic.com/294rwu9.jpg .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22132/discussion-between-seahuston-and-subnivean)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way for drawing the camber line of an airofoil is to load the profile in CATIA. After that in CATIA we can draw circles that are tangent to the both side of profile (suction side and pressure side. Then we can connect center of these circles and consequently we find the camber line accurately.

Answer (score 1):

Is the mean camber line the set of points equidistant from the upper line and the lower line? If that's the definition, it's different from Sanjay's, or at least not obviously-to-me the same.

The most direct way to compute that: cast many rays perpendicular to the upper line, and many rays perpendicular to the lower line, and see where the rays from above intersect the rays from below. The intersections with the nearest-to-equal distances approximate the mean camber line (as defined here); interpolate them, with the differences in distance affecting the weights.

But I'll bet the iterative method you pasted from comments is easier to code, and I guess would converge to the same curve.

Comment: Hi. I'm not exactly sure whether that will work; I'll have to check it on an example. However, I've illustrated the difference between the two (mean and camber line) to clear up the confusion. Hope that helps with the understanding.

Comment: @Rook, So, if you look at your new black diagrams, you will see that the tangents to the circle (and to the actual wing) are bisected by the centre of the circle, as I thought. Shouldn't this mean that, using similar triangles, you don't actually need to drop any perpendiculars, just minimise the distance between the edges?

Comment: @Sanjay - To tell you frankly, I'm not sure anymore. I'll have to check it up first - but, doesn't that come to your 2nd approach (the one suggested in your answer)?